# Want to get data from a JSONObject

Tags: java, android, json, mongodb, android-studio

I am working with android studio and I want to retrieve the data from the database *mongodb*. So I have built the connection and I can get the data in JSON successfully. But when I want to iterate it, it doesn't work.

```
ArrayList<DatabaseSchema> user = new ArrayList<DatabaseSchema>();

String mongoarray = "{ db_list: " + list + "}";
Object o = com.mongodb.util.JSON.parse(mongoarray);
DBObject dbObj = (DBObject) o;
BasicDBList userList = (BasicDBList) dbObj.get("db_list");

for (Object obj : userList) {
     DBObject userObj = (DBObject) obj;
     DatabaseSchema temp = new DatabaseSchema();
     temp.setUsername(userObj.get("username").toString());
     user.add(temp);
}
```

And at the end of this method I want to return the *user*. But when I want to retrieve the *username* of this user I get nothing and there is no error.

**EDIT:**

```
public class DatabaseSchema {
    public String username;

    public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
    return username;
    }
}
```

and I retrieve this input:

> [ { "_id" : { "$oid" : "586.."} , "document" : {
>   "username" : "gmz" } } ]

Comment: are you sure DabaseSchema is the right type ..? also,  using Object class is most of the times not the best practice.

Comment: @Gewure yes it is the right one. Do you have an example how can I implement it without using the object class?

Comment: no, i don't have. i just figured out that casting that much seems quite unnatural.
maybe good guy mkyong can help you with this: http://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/spring-data-mongodb-query-document/

Comment: Can you show us sample json you are trying to parse and add the `DatabaseSchema` class structure  to the post ?

Comment: @Gewure thank you for the link. I will have a look at it and I have added the DatabaseSchema.